# What is the unix command to find catalina.out file in /var directory?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, grep, aix

What is the unix command to find catalina.out file in /var directory ?
I tried the below :

```
find /var -name “catalina.out”
```

But I am getting error Permission denied.

Comment: That's the right command. You can expect several "Permission denied" messages for subdirectories you don't have permission to read. Try appending `2>/dev/null` to discard error messages.

Comment: That's the right command assuming those are normal quotes in the shell and not smart quotes (as they are here).

Answer (score 0):

That error is due to lack of permissions, which depending on your system configuration, distribution etc... If this is a case of your own Ubuntu machine, then `sudo`-ing the command might get you something, so try:

`sudo find /var -name "catalina.out"`

and provide your login password when asked.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this as I don't have sudo access

Comment: I doubt. Have you tried to actually do a `cd /var`? If your user account can't get there, and you don't have sudo access, then you're out of luck. You need to ask your system administrator.

Comment: Is there any way we can use locate command to find the file??